# Whats the point of having more than 1 package files in the src folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, package, src

Some projects like https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr have more than 1 package in the files, what is the reason for having more than 1 package?

Comment: I see only one package on the link you gave.

Comment: Y u no Google ??? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package

Comment: @iKiWiXz in eclipse, under the src folder, there are 3 different names like edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr, edu.sfu.cs.orange.ocr.camera and edu.sfu.cs.orange.ocr.language

Comment: I use to **organize** my projects package into folders, such as `activities`, `classes` and `fragments`. Eclipse has a great fun to prefix these folders with the package name. What a funny joker!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages are organizational units of your application. 
In MVC - based applications you will usually see such things as com.xyz.applicationname.model, 
com.xyz.applicationname.view, com.xyz.applicationname.controller.
The same can be done with android, too, of course and it decomposes the complexity of your 
application. When splattering one package with many classes, the class hierarchy may not be reflected any more. 
Say you have a class, which is the base class for all activities you are developing, and 
another one, which is the base of several UI - handlers, and another one, which is the base of all services.
Within one package it is difficult to detect the use of a class just by looking at it.
When a class is within a com.xyz.applicationname.service - package, it is quiet obvious.
And if within the package there is a class ServiceBase, than it is obvious at the first glance
that this class should be the base of all service implementations.